# Insert an html tag to Django form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Django and bootstrap and would like to add the html tag using bootstrap Icon glyphs, as I failed to do, is like adding attributes to the widgets, but I failed to add the label or, say to directly customize.

This is what leads me Django:

```
<p><label for="id_fecha">Fecha:</label> <input type="text" name="fecha" id="id_fecha" /></p>
```

This is what I want:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" name="fecha" id="id_fecha" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Django's default form rendering is not what you should be using if you want customization. It's a quick and dirty default. Write your own HTML like this; `<div>{{ form.fecha }}<i class="foo"></i></div>`. Or look into making a custom form widget that knows how to render itself with a bootstrap icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have simple template that build form, cleanest way here is to add additional tags by JavaScript. If you are using JQuery, you can use [.after method](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#id_fecha').after('<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>');
```

It saves your template simple.